# Long running functions didn't give response back in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, function, pgadmin

I am experiencing a strange problem with a PostgreSQL database. I have a fairly simple function in which I pass an array of columns and their ID's.

The function loops over the columns array and insert the data into a table.
The problem is that if the columns are less and the data to be inserted is small it successfully runs the function and give me the inserted rows. But if there are many columns it took more than 4 minutes then the function stuck and it didn't give me any response. Even thought the data is inserted into the table.

The function stuck and didn't give the response not even any error. It just keep on running until timeout exception occurs. But 1 thing to notice It successfully inserted the records.

I have tried it with PgAdmin, DBeaver and also by hitting with `C#`, the same results. On small data it successfully give the response and insert the record but on large data it inserted the records but didn't give the response.

EDIT
I have checked the `pg_stat_activity` it shows the completion of the function. the query successfully run and no longer in the `pg_stat_activity` table.
Note there will be 5.9 million leads insertion.
Complete function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION admin.insert_data_into_table(customer_column_names text[], customer_column_ids int[] , schema_name text, dyn_table_name text, bucket_id int, partial_query text)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    n INTEGER := 0;
    offset_counter INTEGER := 0;
    i integer;
    chunk_size integer := 10000;
begin
    EXECUTE format('set search_path to %I', schema_name);
    EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I.%I', schema_name, dyn_table_name) into n;
    for i in 1..array_upper(customer_column_ids, 1)
    loop
        offset_counter = 0;
        loop
        EXIT WHEN offset_counter > n; 
            Execute Format('insert into %s.table (customer_id, customer_column_id, value, bucket_id) 
            select _customer_id, %s, %s, %s from %s.%s %s order by _customer_id offset %s limit %s', 
            schema_name, customer_column_ids[i], customer_column_names[i], bucket_id, schema_name, dyn_table_name, partial_query, offset_counter, chunk_size);
            offset_counter := offset_counter + chunk_size; 
        end loop;
    end loop;
    return n;
end;
$function$;
```

Comment: You need to show us your function. Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete source of that function as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also, how does the `pg_stat_activity` line look when the function is "stuck"? Do I understand right that the function finishes successfully, but that doesn't register on the front end? Investigate some more; currently the question is rather unclear and hard to answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe edited and added the complete function code

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name question edited.

Comment: It is unheard of that no function result is displayed in pgAdmin even though the `state` of the session in `pg_stat_activity` is `idle`.